# How can i select multiple rows by a certain ids in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to select multiple rows in db (using MYSQL).
I create the following query by iterating over array of ids:

```
$ids = array(1,2);
$idq = array();
$q = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE ";
foreach($ids as $id)
{
    $idq[] = "`ID` = '" . $id . "'";
}

$q .= implode(" AND ", $idq);

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1' AND `ID` = '2'
```

For some reason it doesn't seem to work:

The above won't work. Is there a better way?

When I do:

```
`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1'`
```

It works fine but when I add the `AND` ID `= '2'` it won't work at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `WHERE IN`

`SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE`ID`IN  ('1', '2')`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1' AND `ID` = '2'
```

The ID cannot be 1 and 2 at the same time. You should use OR.

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1' OR `ID` = '2'
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` IN (1,2,...)
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1' AND `ID` = '2'

You are saying: I want to go to the beach and to skiing at 5pm of the same day. Result: not possible. You can either go to the beach or to skiing. so your query should look like:

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` = '1' OR `ID` = '2'
or
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE `ID` in (1,2)